# Python: send postgres password with using subprocess

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7

I'm stuck at a dead end with sending password with using subprocess, and I don't know what is wrong. I would be grateful for any tips.

My code :

```
os.system("sudo -u postgres -h " + db_host + " psql postgres -c \"\password\" ")
os.system("sudo -u postgres -h " + db_host + " createuser " + db_user);
print bcolors.WARNING, "Please enter your password for : " + db_user, bcolors.ENDC
str = "sudo -u postgres -h " + db_host + " psql postgres -c \"\password " + db_user + "\""
# os.system(str)
p = subprocess.Popen(['sudo','-u', 'postgres', '-h', db_host, 'psql', 'postgres', "-c", "\password", db_user],stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
p.communicate(raw_input("Please give me a password!")
```

When using `os.system(str)` everything is okay, but I want to catch the typed password from the user and in the future I want to store the password in configuration file. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop what you're doing, and use `psycopg2`. Please. You almost never need to shell out to `psql`. Just connect with the `psycopg2` native client driver for PostgreSQL.

If you need to connect as a superuser, modify `pg_hba.conf` to allow `md5` password authentication from your user and set a password for the `postgres` user.

---

> `os.system("sudo -u postgres -h " + db_host + " psql postgres -c \"\password\" ")`

This doesn't make sense. You're trying to execute the command `-h`. You need to invoke `psql` first.

---

`sudo` tries to avoid reading the password from stdin. It closes its stdin and reopens the current tty directly as a security measure to help stop people wrapping `sudo` with a command that traps the password.

So it's designed to defeat what you are trying to do.

You can:

- Set `NOPASSWD` mode in `sudo` for `psql`;
- Use `sudo -A` with an askpass helper program in the `SUDO_ASKPASS` environment variable. You could write a `SUDO_ASKPASS` that reads the password from a file descriptor inherited from your program by creating a `pipe()` to yourself.
- Use `sudo -n` to disable the password prompt. `sudo` will fail if a password is required.
- ... or best of all, *don't use `sudo` to run `psql`*, just use `psycopg2`